# In what Star Trek episode did non-corporeal aliens assume human form?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek

In what Star Trek episode did aliens assume human form and say something abut feeling a corporeal body again: "to feel the blood flow", "to feel the heart beat and lungs full of air" etc. (or something like that!)

Answer (score 10):

This is from the original Star Trek, Season 2, episode 20; "[Return To Tomorrow](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/51.htm)"

An alien (known as Sargon) inhabits Captain Kirk's body

> **SPOCK:** And if he refuses, Doctor, what do you propose to do with your phaser? That is still Jim's body.
>
> (Kirk convulses briefly, and the sphere has dimmed a lot.)
>
> **KIRK:** Lungs filled with air again. To see again. Heart pumping, arteries surging with blood again. A half a million years. To be
>   again. Your captain has an excellent body, Doctor McCoy. I compliment
>   you both on the condition in which you maintained it.
>
> **SPOCK:** What are your plans for it? Can you exchange places again when you wish?

Comment: Nice, I was just about to start watching [ENT: The crossing](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Crossing_(episode)) to see if it could be a match.

Comment: @Rev1.0: if the answer has saved you from watching *Enterprise*, it’s done some good.

Comment: Ha, thanks for posting this fine example of the Shatnerian School of Acting. :)

Comment: @RobertF - No-one ever accused Shatner of being a good actor. He's enjoyable to watch but that's not quite the same thing.